# ObjectMapper how can I map value In a nested Entity

Tags: swift, core-data, objectmapper

In this scenario using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)

```
[{
"port": "1",
"b": [{
     "c": [{"address": 1}]
     }]
}, {
"port": "2",
"b": [{
     "c": [{"address": 2}]
     }]
}]
```

here C is the entity with row address and port. Now using ObjectMapper how do I set value of port entity C.

I have written this nested part of code

```
class a: NSManagedObject, Mappable {
 @NSManaged var port: NSNumber?
 @NSManaged var b: NSSet?
 private var barr: [b]?
 required public init?(map: Map) {
   let ctx = DbHelper .getContext()
   let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "a", in: ctx)
   super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: ctx)
   mapping(map: map)
}

public func mapping(map: Map) {
  port <- map["port"]
  barr <- map["b"]
  if barr != nil
  {
      b = NSSet(array: barr!)
      barr = nil
  }
 }
}
```

Similarly created and mapped for "B" and "C" Entity

now at "C" I need value of "port" from entity "a".

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: @AhmadF editted the question added what i have currently implemented.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that your json is not valid. You forgot a `"` after port: `"port: "2",`

Here the solution

Model structure:

```
class Port : Mappable {
 var port:String?
 var b: [C]?

 required init?(map: Map) {

 }

 func mapping(map: Map) {
    port <- map["port"]
    b <- map["b"]
 }
}

class C : Mappable {
 var c:[Address]?

 required init?(map: Map) {

 }

 func mapping(map: Map) {
    c <- map["c"]
 }
}

class Address : Mappable {
 var address:Int?

 required init?(map: Map) {

 }

 func mapping(map: Map) {
    address <- map["address"]
 }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
if let json = "yourJson" {
                if let res:[Port] = Mapper<Port>().mapArray(JSONArray: json as! [[String : Any]]) {
                    //your port objects
                }
            }
```

Attention: I do a force cast. You shouldn't. The Objectmapper needs the `[[String : Any]]` format for the `json`.

I recommended to use Alamofire for requests.

With Alamofire it works:

```
    let url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/iw6vj" //your json
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (data) in
        if let json = data.result.value {
            if let res:[Port] = Mapper<Port>().mapArray(JSONArray: json as! [[String : Any]]) {
                //your port objects
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are at the beginning of your project you should use `Codabale` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable. There are a lot of tutorials in the web. Search for Alamofire+Codable and you can handle request + parsing very easily.

A hint: Your naming is very confusing. Have a look for this article https://medium.com/coding-skills/clean-code-101-meaningful-names-and-functions-bf450456d90c This helps for the model structure too.

Comment: thanks for answering but I want to know how will I store value of Port from Class Port to Class C by creating a object port in class C.

Comment: Can you help me out how can I use codable and Store custom objects in Core data ?

Comment: No, I can't. I can help you when you have a specific problem. There are a lot of tutorials for core data: https://medium.com/@kf99916/codable-nsmanagedobject-and-cllocation-in-swift-4-b32f042cb7d3 First hit at google. Search for `core data codable swift`

Comment: I found it i am checking on google about coredata codable  but for this specific problem how will I store value of Port from Class Port to Class C by creating a object port in class C.